# pytest ImportError Package

Tags: python, pytest, importerror

Attempting to test my project recently, I have been getting the following traceback every time.

https://paste.gnome.org/pwkpqejza

Python Version 3.5.3
pytest 3.6.3

Running via `./setup.py test --addopts "tests/ -s"`

The tests run fine in CI, so it is clearly an issue with my configuration.

CI Configuration: platform linux -- Python 3.5.3, pytest-3.7.3, py-1.6.0, pluggy-0.7.1 -- /usr/bin/python3

EDIT: Turned out to be an issue primarily caused by the pytest version as mentioned by @phd. This was caused due to some version pinning which didn't seem to effect the CI. `rm -rf .eggs` solved the problem for me.

Comment: Upgrade the `pytest` package as suggested in the answer, and clean up the `/home/joshsmith/buildstream/.eggs/` dir.

Comment: @phd, "Images cannot easily contain all of the details from an exception. Exceptions contain stack traces which are often very long and won’t fit in an image." From this link, I'm getting the idea that a paste is generally the way to go as opposed to images. Anything else?

Comment: Yes, text is better than pictures — it's copy/paste-able and searchable. There are a lot of tips at https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking and anti-tips at http://idownvotedbecau.se/

Answer (score 1):

[pytest 3.6.3](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/73d787df3a13af635d18464a6560984e78c0b4da/src/_pytest/python.py) really doesn't have `pytest.python.Package`. [pytest 3.7.3](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/70bdacf01aa0917d4499c1aff4f9f2061968a655/src/_pytest/python.py#L540) does. Upgrade your `pytest`.